# How can I wrap only the files that I have on the fixtures path in Cypress

Tags: cypress

***this command getoperationdata it gives me the data stored inside fixtures , I want to wrap only the files into the folder of the screen
= fixturesPath , so when I run the test it wraps the files json inside the fixture folder and not the fixture screen name folder , I need it to wrap only the files inside the fixture screen name folder***

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getOperationData", (screenName, mode) => {
        const fixturesPath = `cypress/fixtures/${screenName}`;
      
        // Read all fixture files in the specified directory
        return cy.task("listFiles", { path: fixturesPath }).then((files) => {
          // Filter out only JSON files
          const jsonFiles = files.filter((file) => file.endsWith(".json"));
      
          // Array to store all data from different files
          const allData = [];
      
          // Loop through all JSON files and collect the data in allData
          return cy.wrap(jsonFiles).each((file) => {
            return cy.readFile(`${fixturesPath}/${file}`).then((operationData) => {
              allData.push(operationData);
            });
          }).then(() => {
            // Concatenate allData into a single array
            const modeData = allData.reduce((acc, data) => acc.concat(data), []);
      
            // Filter the data to find all items with the relevant mode
            const result = mode ? modeData.filter((item) => item.mode === mode) : modeData;
            if (mode && result.length === 0) {
              // Throw an error if mode not found
              throw new Error(`Mode "${mode}" not existing in fixture data.`);
            }
            return cy.wrap(result ? result : []);
          });
        });
      });
```